# want to add colored lines into complex plot legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

here is the code for the plot including the legend:

```
png(filename=paste0(filename2, SubNameStr, "_", date, "_", BlankUncertainty, "-percent-blank-unc_", "no_add_unc", "_", " (R#_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss).png"),
  type="cairo",
  units="cm",
  width=30,
  height=15,
  pointsize=12,
  res=resolution)

par(mar =c(10, 4, 4, 2)+0.1)
plotCI(1:abscissa, 
     LoopVariable[ ,"F_corrected_normed"],
     xlim=c(0, abscissa + 1),
     ylim=c(LoopVariable[1,"weighted_mean_fraction_modern"] -      (LoopVariable[1,"weighted_mean_fraction_modern"] * y),
            LoopVariable[1,"weighted_mean_fraction_modern"] +  (LoopVariable[1,"weighted_mean_fraction_modern"] * y)),
     xaxs="i",
     yaxs="i",
     uiw=LoopVariable[ ,"F_corrected_normed_error_NOSYSERR"], err="y",
     main=(LoopVariable[1,"Samples..Sample_ID"]),
     xlab="", ylab="F_modern",
     pch=19
     )
if (LoopVariable[1,"Job..R"] == "14047/2")
abline(h=IAEA_C2consensus, lwd=1, col="blue", lty=11)

if (LoopVariable[1,"Job..R"] == "18331/3")
abline(h=TIRI_Iconsensus, lwd=1, col="blue", lty=11)

if (LoopVariable[1,"Job..R"] == "24889/3")
abline(h=FIRI_Cconsensus, lwd=1, col="blue", lty=11)

if (LoopVariable[1,"Job..R"] == "18331/4")
abline(h=TIRI_Jconsensus, lwd=1, col="blue", lty=11)

if (LoopVariable[1,"Job..R"] == "24889/4")
abline(h=FIRI_DFconsensus, lwd=1, col="blue", lty=11)

if (LoopVariable[1,"Job..R"] == "24889/5")
abline(h=FIRI_Econsensus, lwd=1, col="blue", lty=11)

if (LoopVariable[1,"Job..R"] == "24889/9")
abline(h=FIRI_Iconsensus, lwd=1, col="blue", lty=11)

abline(h=LoopVariable[1,"weighted_mean_fraction_modern"], lwd=1, col="red")
mtext(paste0("no additional error added, ", BlankUncertainty, " Blk unc, ",  date))
if (LoopVariable[1,"Job..R"] == "14047/2") {
legend("bottom",
     xpd = TRUE,
     inset=c(0,-0.6),

       legend=c(paste0("degrees of freedom = ",  LoopVariable[1,"degrees_of_freedom"]),
                paste0("Chi square                 = ", LoopVariable[1,"Chi_square"]),
                paste0("Chi square reduced = ", LoopVariable[1,"Chi_square_reduced"]),
                paste0(" F_weighted_mean  = ", LoopVariable[1,"weighted_mean_fraction_modern"]),
                paste0(" F_consensus           = ", IAEA_C2consensus))

                )

     }
else {       

legend("bottom",
   xpd = TRUE,
   inset=c(0,-0.6),

   legend=c(paste0("degrees of freedom ", LoopVariable[1,"degrees_of_freedom"]),
            paste0("Chi square ", LoopVariable[1,"Chi_square"]),
            paste0("Chi square reduced ", LoopVariable[1,"Chi_square_reduced"]),
            paste0(lty=1, col="red", " F_weighted_mean = ", LoopVariable[1,"weighted_mean_fraction_modern"])
            )
   )}


dev.off()
```

The question I have is, How can I add a short red and blue line to my last to lines for the legend so that the F_consensus and the F_weighted_mean values are visible dedicated to the right colored `abline` in the plot.
Here is the plot produced form my sample code:
[image]

Comment: After looking at the documentation it looks pretty easy, but it doesn't appear that there is any data for testing. (And you didn't load pkg:plotrix.)

Comment: `@BondeDust` I did load the library plotrix, I just did not mention it here. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to specify the parameters `lty`  and `col` like this:

```
legendText <- c(paste0("degrees of freedom = ",  LoopVariable[1,"degrees_of_freedom"]), 
                paste0("Chi square                 = ", LoopVariable[1,"Chi_square"]), 
                paste0("Chi square reduced = ", LoopVariable[1,"Chi_square_reduced"]),
                paste0(" F_weighted_mean  = ", LoopVariable[1,"weighted_mean_fraction_modern"]),
                paste0(" F_consensus           = ", IAEA_C2consensus))
legend("bottom",
       legendText,
       xpd = TRUE,
       inset=c(0,-0.6),
       col = c(NA,NA,NA,'red','blue'),
       lty = c(NA,NA,NA,1,2))
```

I usually supply the text labels positionally (second or third argument depending), since it's confusing that here is an argument called `legend` to the function `legend()`.

Comment: `@Jthorpe` When I add your last two lines of code under my 5 lines of code in the legend, then the legends expands by three empty lines followed by a line with content `red`, next line `blue`, three empty lines, next line shows `1` and the last line shows `2`. I completely agree that I have to specify the parameters `lty` and `col`, but could you please give me the complete solution?